# Can a same task be launched any time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There is an executed `AsyncTask` :

```
someTask = new myTask(myActivity.this);
someTask.execute(someString);
```

Can I make an execution in the `onPostExecute` of the implementation of myTask :

```
this.execute(someOtherString);
```

Or do I have to recreate the task and then execute it ?

Comment: How is it possible that "this" points to the myTask??

Comment: @micky: Because the function onPostExecute resides inside a class that extends AsyncTask. In their example, myTask.

Comment: So here this points to myTask right???Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of AsyncTask can only be run once.

You could create a new instance of your AsyncTask and execute that. You would also want to be careful of creating an infinite loop though. You need a well defined end condition.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

Comment: So I must create another instance of MyTask then ? yes the number of execution is just limited to 4 , so 3 other executions should be launched in the `onPostExecute` :)

Comment: Exactly, simply run your (new myTask(myActivity.this)).execute(...); again. However many times as necessary. Make absolutely doubly sure that it is limited though. You should pass the number of times it has been run into the task somehow. So it knows. Into the constructor for example.